# Memory deallocation using slice::from_raw_parts_mut and ptr::drop_in_place in rust

Tags: rust, slice

I saw a piece of code online that was dropping allocated memory using a combination of `std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut()` and `std::ptr::drop_in_place()`. Below is a piece of code that allocates an array of ten integers and then de-allocates it:

```
use std::{
    alloc::{alloc, Layout},
    ptr::NonNull,
};

fn main() {
    let len: usize = 10;
    let layout: Layout = Layout::array::<i32>(len).unwrap();
    let data: NonNull<i32> = unsafe { NonNull::new(alloc(layout) as *mut i32).unwrap() };

    unsafe {
        std::ptr::drop_in_place(std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(data.as_ptr(), len));
    }
}
```

The return type of `std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut()` is a mutable slice `&mut [T]`, but the argument of  `std::ptr::drop_in_place()` is `*mut T`. It seems to me that the conversion happens automatically. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here since it shouldn't be allowed. Would someone explain what exactly is happening here?

Comment: Actually, there is a conversion from `&mut [T]` into `*mut [T]`. What specific step of this code do you think should fail?

Comment: @rodrigo The implicit conversion from `&mut [T]` into `*mut [T]`. I'm new to rust but I fail to find any doc that mentions this implicit conversion. Also note that in this example the conversion is from `&mut [T]` to `*mut T` not what you mentioned (`&mut [T]` into `*mut [T]`)

Comment: Implicit conversion (coercion) from reference to raw pointer is documented [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types). I think you are wrong with what happens here: `drop_in_place()` takes a `*mut T` but that `T` is automatically deduced from the context, If you pass in a `&mut [i32]`, then `T` will be resolved as `[i32]`, so you are converting from `&mut [i32]` to `*mut [i32]`.

Comment: @rodrigo Would you write an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(data.as_ptr(), len)` you are building a value of type `&mut [i32]`.

Then you are passing it to `drop_in_place()` that is defined more or less as:

```
fn drop_in_place<T: ?Sized>(to_drop: *mut T)
```

So you are coercing a `&mut [i32]` into a `*mut T`, that is solved in two steps: there is an automatic coercion from [reference to pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types), and then `T` is resolved as `[i32]` which is the type whose `drop` is actually called.

(You may think that the automatic coercion from reference to pointer is dangerous and should not be automatic, but it is actually totally safe. What is unsafe is usually what you do with the pointer afterwards. And actually there are a couple of uses of raw pointers that are safe, such as `std::ptr::eq` or `std::ptr::hash`).

Slices implement `Drop::drop` by simply iterating over the elements and calling `drop_in_place` in each of them. This is a clever way to avoid writing the loop manually.

But note a couple of things about this code:

1. `drop_in_place` will call `Drop::drop` on every element of the slice, but since they are of type `i32` it is effectively a no-op. I guess that your original code uses a generic type.
2. `drop_in_place` does not free the memory, for that you need a call to `std::alloc::dealloc`.